# Eclipse kepler enable autocomplete (content assist) jsf composite components attributes

Tags: eclipse, jsf, autocomplete, attributes, composite

What should be project settings to enable jsf composite components autocomplete?
I already checked Properties -> Project Facets -> JavaServer Faces 2.0, but that doesn't help to get composite components attributes suggested.
Any ideas would really help,
Thanks